# Should patients vary their own dosage when using injections for erectile dysfunction?

Tags: urology, erectile-dysfunction

There seem to be two different approaches taken by doctors, and I am wondering if there are any formal guidelines or "best practices?"

1. In the approach I have experienced, the doctor shows the patient how
   to perform the injection.  The patient then injects a small dose in
   the office, and waits to determine the effect.  The doctor then
   sends the patient home with instructions to gradually increase the
   dosage, in small amounts, until he is able to achieve a satisfactory
   erection.
2. The other approach is for the patient to make a series of
   appointments.  At each appointment, the patient injects a
   pre-determined amount, under the doctor's supervision, until the
   right dosage is determined.